# munin graph interpretation

Tags: munin

I have a quick question.

The following mysqlslowquerys / second graph marked 3 entries last day.
http://img8.imageshack.us/i/picturert.png/

how do you interpret the peak legend?

Is the peak ~3 miliseconds or ~3 minutes?

Am asking this because "avg" is marked as u(microseconds)

Thanks,

Comment: // , Good question, cmancre. Wouldst care to update the title really quick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical scale is "slow queries/second", and as you had less than 1 slow query/second, Munin tags the value as 'm' (for 'mili').

If you are really worried about it, take a look at `/usr/share/munin/munin-graph`.

Comment: Miliseconds. So one pointless query taking 3 miliseconds to complete. I think I have nothing to worry about. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you had 3 datapoints where you had 3 slow queries / second. The "avg" is pointless since you don't have more values which were more than 0 so the average is going to be a really small number anyhow. Your peak was 3 slow queries / second.